# Python zipfile module doesn't compress files

Tags: python, compression, python-zipfile

I have a problem with compression in Python.
I know I should call the ZIP_DEFLATED method when writing to make the zip file compressed, but it does not work for me.
I have 3 PDF documents in the C:zip directory. 
When I run the following code it works just fine:

```
import os,sys
list = os.listdir('C:\zip')
file = ZipFile('test.zip','w')
for item in list:
    file.write(item)
file.close()
```

It makes the test.zip file without the compression.
When I change the fourth row to this:

```
file = ZipFile('test.zip','w', compression = ZIP_DEFLATED)
```

It also makes the test.zip file without the compression.
I also tried to change the write method to give it the *compress*_ *type* argument:

```
file.write(item, compress_type = ZIP_DEFLATED)
```

But that doesn't work either.
I use Python version 2.7.4 with Win7.
I tired the code with another computer (same circumstances, Win7 and Python 2.7.4), and it made the test.zip file compressed just like it should.
I know the zlib module should be available, when I run this:

```
import zlib
```

It doesn't return an error, also if there would be something wrong with the zlib module the code at the top should had return an error too, so I suspect that zlib isn't the problem.

Comment: How are you checking whether the end zip file has been created with or without compression?

Comment: The documentation for the `Zipfile` constructor says "If `ZIP_DEFLATED` is specified but the zlib module is not available, `RuntimeError` is also raised." So if you don't get an error it should work. Note, it's not necessary to specify a `compress_type` keyword argument on a `write()` call unless you want to override the value given for the `compression` parameter to the constructor.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

By default the ZIP module only store data, to compress it you can do this:

```
import zipfile
try:
    import zlib
    mode= zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED
except:
    mode= zipfile.ZIP_STORED

zip= zipfile.ZipFile('zipfilename', 'w', mode)
zip.write(item)
zip.close()
```

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't working either.
The mode variable returns an '8', so it sets the mode to ZIP_DEFLATED succesfully, but the zipfile is still too big.

Comment: "Still too big", but poorly compressed or uncompressed at all?

Comment: Sorry, it seems to work now, looks like I made a mistake in the code eariler when trying it with other files.
After that I was only working with the 3 PDF documents and the size of the compressed file was near as big as the size of the 3 PDF documents, and I thought the compression is still not working.
Thanks for the help!

Comment: Ok, you are welcome! If you think this is a valid answer to your question then will be nice if you mark it as accepted!

Comment: How is ZIP_STORED the default?!?! D: Whow! Thanks for clearing this up! 7zip makes much smaller zips tho 

Answer (score 0):

In case you get here as I did, I'll add something.
If you use [`ZipInfo`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipinfo-objects) objects, they **always** override the compression method specified while creating the `ZipFile`, which is then useless.

So either you set their compression method (no parameter on the constructor, you must set the attribute) or specify the compression method when calling `write` (or `writestr`).

```py
import zlib
from zipfile import ZipFile, ZipInfo, ZIP_DEFLATED

def write_things():
    zip_buffer = io.BytesIO()
    with ZipFile(file = zip_buffer, mode = "w", compression = ZIP_DEFLATED) as zipper:
        # Get some data to write
        fname, content, zip_ts = get_file_data()
        file_object = ZipInfo(fname, zip_ts)
        zipper.writestr(file_object, content)   # Surprise, no compression

#       This is required to get compression
#       zipper.writestr(file_object, content, compress_type = ZIP_DEFLATED)
```